# BehaviorSubject isn't being 'nexted'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, rxjs-observables

For reasons unknown to me I'm not able to 'next' the BehaviorSubject. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm doing it step by step with video tutorial, got almost everything like in that tutorial and it's still not working for me.

**chat-window.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit,  } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ChatroomsService } from '../../services/chatrooms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-window',
  template: `
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <app-room-title [room]="room"></app-room-title>
        <app-message></app-message>
        <app-input></app-input>
    </div>
</div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./chat-window.component.css']
})
export class ChatWindowComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  room: any;

  constructor(private chatroomsService: ChatroomsService, private acivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.chatroomsService.roomTaken.subscribe(chatroom => {
        this.room = chatroom;
      }));
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.acivatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(parameters => {
        const chatroomId = parameters.get('roomID');
        this.chatroomsService.changeTheRoom.next(chatroomId);
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {subscription.unsubscribe(); });
  }
}
```

**room-title.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-room-title',
  template: `<p>{{room.title}}</p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./room-title.component.css']
})
export class RoomTitleComponent {
  @Input() room: any;
  constructor(){}
}
```

**chatrooms.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatroomsService {
  public changeTheRoom: BehaviorSubject<string | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public roomTaken: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.roomTaken = this.changeTheRoom.pipe(switchMap(roomID => {
      if (roomID) {
        return angularFirestore.doc(`chatRooms/${roomID}`).valueChanges();
      }
      return of(null);
    }));
  }
}
```

When I'm switching on a different route, the BehaviorSubject isn't being 'nexted', it remains null. That's why, when I try to display 'title' of room, I'm getting an error, that can't find property 'title' of null. I beg for help, I'm pulling my hair out~! Thanks in advance.
/Ernest

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an option to delete a question but didn't succeed. Anyway, I found my mistake: in app-routing I had:
{path: ': rootID"[...]} instead of {path':roomID'[...]}. The space between the colon and 'roomID' destroyed everything. Thanks anyway for anyone who took a look ;)